# What would happen if p-type and n-type semiconductor is connected by ohmic contact

Tags: semiconductor-physics

I was wondering what would happen if I separate the n-type and p-type regions in a pn junction diode and connect them with an ohmic contact. Or let me put it another way:
Can a pn junction diode be formed if I connect p-type and n-type semiconductors with ohmic contact? Would it become a plain conductor? or it would still be a diode?

Comment: Consider a p-type | metal | n-type sandwich. You now have two metal-semiconductor Schottky diodes.

Comment: @JonCuster why not ohmic contact?

Comment: Because an ohmic contact is really boring here - you have a resistor between two chunks of silicon.

Comment: @JonCuster, doe it mean that if p-type and n-type regions are connected with ohmic contact, it would be a conductor and the diode no longer exists?   Could I simulate that effect with some numerical software?

Answer (score 0):

I-V characteristics of p-type semiconductor with metal, vary widely with temperature. It hinders reliability, which is supported by n-type. Hence it's not used. Read and see figure 7 and just below it https://www.researchgate.net/publication/250341749_Diffusion-Welded_Al_Contacts_to_p-Type_SiC.

Another reference figure https://www.researchgate.net/figure/I-V-characteristics-of-Schottky-diodes-vs-PN-diodes_fig1_366763152